# Impactful fixed-effect identification with open data

Tags: reference-request, fixed-effects, identification, causal-inference

For a replication project, I am looking for impactful (and ideally somewhat recent) papers that use fixed-effects as their main identification strategy *and make their data publicly available*.

By publicly available, I mean:

- Ideally directly available together with the paper, either on the journal's website, or on the author's website.
- Papers based on publically available data could also be useful but as a second-best only (this is for a replication project, so any steps such as having to reconstruct the data from public sources which could introduce differences with the original analysis is not ideal),
- I am *not* interested at this stage in papers that require emailing the author to obtain the data.

This is not really (at all) my area of research, so any help in identifying the best candidates would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you only look for papers where authors make their data explicitly available themselves or do papers based on public data, or where journal makes data available per request count?

Comment: @1muflon1: Thanks for giving me a chance to clarify this point, I'll do that in the question directly.

Comment: You can have a look at the webpage of the [American Economic Review](https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/aer). Most empirical papers publish their data and code on the website as well.